# Liferay: Portlet titles not saving

Tags: portlet, liferay

I'm using liferay with web content and iframe portlets. The default title for these portlets are 'web content display' and 'iframe'. After I change these I'm still seeing them revert back to default on other PCs.

Anyone come across this before?

Cheers,
Jonesy

Answer (score 3):

which version of liferay are you using?

How are you changing them? You can change them in two ways, try both:

1. Double click on the title (this will change it for the language you are currently in)
2. From the look and Feel pop up (this should allow you to change the title for any language, althoug this was not working properly in some older versions)

Comment: thanks for your reply. I'm using Liferay Portal Community Edition 6.0.5 CE. I've tried changing both ways. I change iframe to something else but on other computers (my boss included :/ ) it stays as iframe

Comment: Are both of you using the same language? I just verified that there is a bug in 6.0.5 that has already been resolved (in Enterprise Edition and future 6.0.6) that doesn't allow you to change the title from the look and feel view. In order to change the title, you have to view the page in the desired language and change the title by double clicking on it. You can do this for all the languages you need.

Comment: I have changed the title but on some users PCs the title changes back to default. it's very strange

Comment: I've tried changing the titles for both English UK and English US but for some reason English US doens't save. Next time I opn the look and feel to change it the English US field is empty again